# Java converting byte array to string UTF-8

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string. The problem is that UTF-8 won't work. I can't show "ü", "ä" or something like this. Can anyone help me?

```
public static String byteToString(byte[] bytes) {
    String str = new String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8);

    return str;
}
```

Would be nice if it works down until API 8 Android

Comment: have you try `new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`?

Comment: That should work. Are you sure the data is UTF-8? How do you display it back?

Comment: Requires at least API 9. Yes I'm sure that the data is UTF-8 and I display it in a TextView with .setText()

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
String str = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
```

Comment: @Phil Just to help you better, can you please update your question by adding two things?: 1 - the byte array input, and 2 - the String you're expecting from such byte array

Comment: This does not work, It works in C# but not in Java.